# Populate dropdown with data from MS Access

Tags: javascript, database, ms-access, drop-down-menu, populate

I'm trying to populate a dropdown with the data form a MS Access database.

My database of categories consists of a table named **cat** with a field named **Cat**.

I am not very good at either Javascript or VB, but I'm still trying to learn. Having tried different methods for a couple of days without luck I'm asking you guys. 
I realize there might be some mistakes in the posted code.

So far I have this:

```
sub getCat

    SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM cat ORDER BY Cat"
    Set rsData=conn.Execute(SQL_query)

end sub
```

Dropdown:

```
<select name="getCat" id="myoptions"></select>
```

Creating options:

```
var  x = "rsData('Cat'), rsData.MoveNext"

var options = x.split(",");

var select = document.getElementById('myoptions');
for(var i=0; i<options.length; i++)
  select.options[i] = new Option(options[i], i);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you're better off building the content of the SELECT on the server as HTML:

```
<%
var sel = ""

do until rsData.EOF
   sel = sel & "<option value='" & rsData("Cat") & "'>" & rsData("Cat") & "</option">
   rsData.MoveNext
loop
%>

<select name="getCat" id="myoptions"><%=sel %></select>
```

Comment: Seems simply, but I'm not getting any options or output at all. The select is just blank.

Could it have anything to do with the fact that it is running in an offline .hta?

Comment: It should be in a regular ASP file.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
With the help of Diodeus. A bit different from what you proposed, but you got me there :-)

```
sub getcat
    SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM categori ORDER BY Cat"
    Set rsData = conn.Execute(SQL_query)
    strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "<select>"
    do until rsData.EOF
    strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "<option value='" & rsData("Cat") & "'>" & rsData("Cat") & "</option>"
    rsData.Movenext
    Loop
    strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "</select>"
    catbox.innerHTML = strHTML2
end sub
```

And place a `<span>` where I want the dropdown:

```
<span id="catbox"></span>
```